# Why passing function reference is failing while using function declaration is not?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, functional-programming

Following code fails:

```js
array.map(String.prototype.toLowerCase)
```

Throws `Uncaught TypeError: String.prototype.toLowerCase called on null or undefined`. Indeed, `this` is not set, I got it.

But what's weird is that following code returns an array of empty strings without failing:

```js
array.map((s) => String.prototype.toLowerCase(s))
```

Any idea why? **Note that I know this is not the way of having an array of lowercased strings.** I'm just wondering why these two approaches behave differently.

In other words, what is the difference between `.map(String.prototype.toLowerCase)` and `.map((s) => String.prototype.toLowerCase(s))`? I thought is was identical, but obviously, it behaves differently. Note that here, `String.prototype.toLowerCase` could be replaced by anything.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the difference between `.map(String.prototype.toLowerCase)` and
>   `.map((s) => String.prototype.toLowerCase(s))`

For the first case when you get the function outside of an object `(String.prototype.toLowerCase)` you lose your context, so you context is null and `map` tries to call on `null or undefined`. With the first solution you can't get the desired result, because you need to pass a context to the `toLowerCase` function, which must be **each item of the array**, but you don't get **that each item of array**.

For the second case you need to pass **context** which is the `item` to the `String.prototype.toLowerCase` via `call` function.

```js
var array = ['ASD', 'BSD'];

var lowered = array.map(item => String.prototype.toLowerCase.call(item));

console.log(lowered);
```

Comment: This won't work neither and does not really answer the question. In other words, what is the difference between `.map(String.prototype.toLowerCase)` and `.map((s) => String.prototype.toLowerCase(s))`? I thought is was identical, but obviously, it behaves differently.

Comment: I think this is not fully true, but it helped me figuring out the answer though, so thanks ;) Basically, IMO, first one has this set to undefined while second one has this set to String.prototype. See my own answer.

Answer (score 2):

The second approach `array.map((s) => String.prototype.toLowerCase(s))` doesn't throw an error, because `toLowerCase` isn't taken out of context, i.e. the method still has `String.prototype` as its receiver.

`String.prototype.toLowerCase(s))` returns an empty string, because the argument `s` is discarded. `toLowerCase` takes it value from its receiving object instead. The receiving object is `String.protoype`. To get the actual string the prototype must be converted to string. This happens with the `String.prototype.toString` method, which evaluates to `""`. Hence `String.prototype.toLowerCase(s))` evaluates to `""`.

You can verify this behavior by changing the `toString` method:

```js
String.prototype.toString = () => "FOO";
console.log(String.prototype.toLowerCase()); // "foo"
```

Answer (score 1):

The diffrence between `.map(String.prototype.toLowerCase) and .map((s) => String.prototype.toLowerCase(s))` is that `.map((s) => String.prototype.toLowerCase(s))` takes an arrow function which is an anonymous function. According to definition of arrow function 
"**An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function expression and does not bind its own this, arguments, super, or new.target.**"
An arrow function does not create its own this, the this value of the enclosing execution context is used.
using `.map(String.prototype.toLowerCase)` will not work as you are not passing any execution context to it but it's looking for one to execute.
For example in the below code

```
function Person(){
  this.age = 0;

  setInterval(() => {
    this.age++; // |this| properly refers to the person object
  }, 1000);
}

var p = new Person();
```

Please check this link 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I think you're wrong with "the this value of the enclosing execution context is used". Basically, IMO, first one has this set to undefined while second one has this set to String.prototype. See my own answer.

Comment: You are correct but my opinion was related to the sample code i provided below where `this` refers to the `Person` class object and not to the global window object

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it finally:

- first one has `this` set to `undefined`, equivalent to:

```js
.map((s) => String.prototype.toLowerCase.call(undefined, s))
```

- while second one has `this` set to `String.prototype`, equivalent to:

```js
.map((s) => String.prototype.toLowerCase.call(String.prototype, s))
```

Now, the question is, why `String.prototype.toLowerCase()` is returning an empty string... But this deserves another question :)